# rackup in Netbeans project

Tags: ruby, netbeans, rack

How can I configure a Netbeans Ruby project so that it does not run a Ruby interpreter (a Ruby "platform"), but starts up rackup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've copied rack gem into [project_path]/vendor/rack-1.0.0

Then set run configuration as follows:

**Main script: rack-1.0.0/bin/rackup**
*Hit 'Browse...' button to choose the right file*

**Arguments: -p 3004**
*Replace 3004 by the needed port*

**Working directory: [project_path]**
*Replace by the actual project path*

And it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I attempted to do something similar myself: to run my project through a Rack container (the way it is meant to run in production). I used [trinidad](http://github.com/calavera/trinidad) as the rackup container (JRuby platform) and in the Ruby VM arguments in netbeans, I put:

```
-S trinidad -r config.ru
```

While this works fine from the terminal, it doesn't work at all from Netbeans and the errors are unhelpful.

Would appreciate a good answer to this one too. Running a specific class is not a useful way of running a Ruby web app intended for a Rack container.